# Wieso heißt es „Universität zu Köln“?

Tags: difference, word-choice

Wieso heißt es „Universität zu Köln“ und nicht einfach  „Universität Köln“ oder „Kölner Universität“?
Falls es Dialekt ist, wieso sagen wir „Kölner Dom“ und nicht „Dom zu Köln“?
Und warum wird die Präposition *zu* verwendet und nicht z.B. *nach*?

Comment: "Dom zu Köln" is perfectly fine. In general,  "zu" when referring to a place is a bit oldfashioned/formal though.

Comment: Weitere Universitäten mit präpositionaler Ortsangabe: Humboldt-Universität zu Berlin, Christian-Albrechts-Universität zu Kiel, Universität zu Lübeck, Fernuniversität in Hagen. Übrigens werden diese offiziellen Namen so kaum benutzt, zumindest nicht außerhalb der jeweiligen Hochschule und dem unmittelbaren Umfeld. Eine Zeitung würde von Erkenntnissen berichten, die jemand „von der Universität Kiel“ gewonnen hat, und man würde sagen, daß jemand „von der Uni Köln“ einen Vortrag hält oder jemand anderes sich „an der Fernuni Hagen“ eingeschrieben hat.

Comment: Das "zu" ist noch ein Überbleibsel aus einer Zeit, als es noch Drachen und Feen gab. Es lässt die Uni in einem altehrwürdigen Glanz erstrahlen...

Comment: Ich glaube, schon Heine benutzt *zu* im *Wintermärchen* so nur noch ironisch, siehe die ersten Zeilen von Caput III und IV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Formulierung

> <*wichtiges Gebäude*> **zu** <*Stadt*>

ist alt und durchaus gängig:

Google liefert viele Dome, die den Namen »*Dom zu xxx*« tragen:

- Dom zu Gurk
- Dom zu Speyer
- Dom zu Graz
- Dom zu Salzburg
- Dom zu Köln
- Dom zu Aachen
- Dom zu Riga
- Dom zu Worms
- Dom zu Maria Saal
- ...

Neben den Domen gibt es auch viele Universitäten, die nach dem selben Schema benannt und bekannt sind:

- Universität zu Köln
- Universität zu Lübeck
- Universität zu Bonn
- Universität zu Berlin
- ...

Auch »Münster zu xxx« ist zu finden:

- Münster zu Ulm
- Münster zu Aachen
- Münster zu Freiburg im Breisgau
- ...

Alle Listen sind unvollständig. Auffallend ist, dass diese Formulierung (meinen Recherchen zufolge) nur für große institutionelle Gebäude verwendet wird, und dann auch nur dann, wenn diese Gebäude schon mehrere Jahrhunderte alt sind.

Diese Formulierung sagt aus, dass der ehrwürdige Dom, das ehrwürdige Münster, die ehrwürdige Uni zu der genannte Stadt gehört, und für diese Stadt wichtig und möglicherweise sogar identitätsstiftend ist.

Comment: Feierabend, Dom zu!

Answer (score 3):

Ich wurde bei meinem Dienstantritt an der Universität zu Köln darüber informiert, dass die Universität von den Bürgern der Stadt Köln gestiftet worden sei, um der Stadt Köln eine erhöhte Bedeutung als Universitätsstadt hinzuzufügen. Damit grenze sich die UzK (so lautet das offizielle Akronym) von anderen Universitäten ab, die eine Stiftung des Landes oder des jeweiligen Herrschers gewesen sind; es dokumentiert auch eine gewisse Unabhängigkeit gegenüber der jeweiligen Landesregierung und eine starke Bindung an die Stadt Köln.
Letzteres wird unter anderem dokumentiert, indem die Neujahrsansprachen gemeinsam von Rektor und Oberbürgermeister der Stadt Köln als „Hausherren“ gehalten werden.