# Why do most German "Wirtshaus" names start with "zu"?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, brand-name

For example: *Zum Schusterjungen*, *Zur Post*, *Zum Flaucher*.

The first thought was "going to a place" which fits for any named after locations. But there are some more figurative names, so I wondered if the pattern, if there is one, is to toast to the object/place. Or maybe there's no pattern.

This has been hard to google.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Regarding your profile you are from UK. A very short search says that in UK it is common to have a restaurant name like "the xy" (and maybe where xy can be a place or person) - is that right? Then it sounds there is a "transferable", because in France you have things like "chez xy" which is "bei ..." while xy here is the chef.

Comment: (and my search was just your question title^^)

Comment: "Zum Flaucher" is in Munich, isn't it? Flaucher is a part of the Isar, and the word is not used elsewhere in Germany.

Comment: Althoug quite a number of restaurant names start with "zum" or "zur", I doubt that **most** names do. But the question is very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zu is a beast as a preposition and its usage can widely vary. [Duden](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zu) lists the definition for the particular usage as follows, in the same category as the usage "zu Hause sein" (at home):

> 1. c) kennzeichnet den Ort, die Lage des Sichbefindens, Sichabspielens von etwas
>    - ...
>    - (in Namen von Gaststätten) Gasthaus zu den Drei Eichen

My personal interpretation of this usage is a stylized description of the building; "Zur Post" is "by post office" and "Zum Löwen" might merely mean "with lion signage" as knut commented. For a bonus, the "The Prancing Pony" inn in *Lord of the Rings* was translated as ["Zum Tänzelnden Pony"](https://lotr.fandom.com/de/wiki/Zum_T%C3%A4nzelnden_Pony) in German.

Found more discussion in another forum at UPenn LDC [Language Log - Ask Language Log: German restaurant-name zum?](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=25216) Seems to be an indeed popular question, where no one likely had definitive explanation why *zu* is used for this purpose, other than it being a tradition or a formulated phrase.

Similar question of usage of *zu* have appeared in GLSE before. [Meaning of "zu" in the name of a Gasthof](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15987/meaning-of-zu-in-the-name-of-a-gasthof). My answer above can be interpreted as an elaboration on Ingmar's answer to this. Another example of usage of *zu* for building albeit a bit different is asked in [Wieso heißt es „Universität zu Köln“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26306/wieso-hei%C3%9Ft-es-universit%C3%A4t-zu-k%C3%B6ln). This again is not "(toasting) *to*", merely describing its location and/or affiliation.

Comment: I like the interpretation referring to signage, since historically, houses did not have numbers, but often signs with animals or something related to their craft.

Answer (score 2):

Your first idea is right. Imagine a Wirtshaus close to a linden (lime). The famous place in this town is this tree. So there is no real name of this Wirtshaus like e.g. *'Peters Kneipe'*, but it's simply the Wirtshaus next to the linden, thus das *'Wirtshaus zur Linde'*.

Comment: I wondering how this explanation fit names like „zum Löwen“. Especially when you consider that said animal isn’t a frequent occurrence in Central Europe.

Comment: Lions are often used as heraldic animals. So it could be, that the Wirthshaus is in the house with the lion over the door.

Comment: I doubt that this a good explanation.